# Some questions around clone/copy TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for clone/copy a `tr` element from a modal to a page.

```
$(function () {
    $('#toggleCheckbox').on('click', function () {
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', $toggle);
        $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', !$toggle);
    });

    $('#resultadoNormaBody').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
        var $my_checkbox = $(this);
        var $my_tr = $my_checkbox.closest('tr');
        if ($my_checkbox.prop('checked')) {
            $my_tr.addClass('copyMe');
        }

        var $all_checkboxes = $my_checkbox.closest('tbody').find('input[type=checkbox]');

        $all_checkboxes.each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', false);
                return false;
            }

            $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', true);
        });
    });

    $('button#btnAplicarNorma').on('click', function (ev) {
        var $tr_to_append = $('#resultadoNormaBody').find('tr.copyMe');

        $('#tablaNorma').removeAttr('style');
        $('#alertSinNorma').hide();

        if ($tr_to_append.length) {
            $tr_to_append.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
            $tr_to_append.clone().appendTo('#normaBody').removeClass('copyMe');
            $tr_to_append.removeClass('copyMe');
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

But I'm having some issues:

1. If I mark all checkboxes using the first on the table head then I the code stop working and doesn't clone any `tr` even if all of them are marked
2. How do I avoid to `clone/copy` the same `tr` twice?
3. It's possible to modify the checkbox before clone it? If you take a look at the example you'll notice how the clone `tr` copy exactly as the one on the modal and I want to uncheck the checkbox first, it's possible?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/wq51zL9x/2/) is a fiddle to play with, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your checkboxes inside the table do not really get properly triggered when you programmatically set them selected. To make sure all associated Events get properly triggered you should be triggering a .click() event instead:

```
  $("#resultadoNormaBody").find("input:checkbox").click();
```

to ensure that you don't end up with duplicate clones the easiest thing is to not clone all the rows in one batch, but iterate thru them, and comparing the html to the ones that have already been added like this:

```
//fetch all the rows that have already been cloned
            var clonedRows = $("#normaBody").find("tr");

            //iterate thru all the rows that have been checked
            $.each($tr_to_append, function (i, v) {
                var added = false;  
                //fetch their html (for easier compare)
                var currentRowHtml = $(v).html();
                //now compare against the rows that have already been cloned
                $.each(clonedRows, function (i, cRow) {
                    var clonedRowHtml = $(cRow).html();
                    if (currentRowHtml == clonedRowHtml) {
                        added = true;
                    }
                });
                //if the row hasn't been added yet- go ahead and clone it now
                if (!added) {
                    $(v).clone().appendTo('#normaBody').removeClass('copyMe');
                }

            });
```

Here's a link to your updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wq51zL9x/4/

Here is some more info on comparing table rows: [Compare two tables rows and remove if match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561937/compare-two-tables-rows-and-remove-if-match)

and here's the more elaborate answer to using .click()
[Need checkbox change event to respond to change of checked state done programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392192/need-checkbox-change-event-to-respond-to-change-of-checked-state-done-programmat)